# How can I check if a particular class exists (html/css)?

Tags: html, css

I use the following code which get applied on two different pages because both pages are using the same element:

```
.SocialBar {
display: none;
}
```

But I want the code to be applied to one page only. On the page where I want it, the following class exists:

```
.PersonalHome-interests.u-mbg
```

Is it somehow possible that I insert .PersonalHome-interests.u-mbg over the thing with the Newsticker and only let check whether the line PersonalHome-interests.u-mbg exists and if so, then Newsticker = display: none apply?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I use Stylish / Stylus. A good solution would be @-moz-document url but the problem is that it's the same url for both pages, you can just switch between two designs and I just want the change at one view.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your'e asking. You want to *hide* elements that have *both* the classes `.SocialBar` and `.PersonalHome-interests`, but *show* elements that *only* have the class `.SocialBar`?

Comment: If you have the CSS that has `.SocialBar` linked to web page, it will affect that page, unless you overwrite it. If you only want `.PersonalHome-interests.u-mbg.SocialBar{ display:none; }` on the CSS page that is used for multiple HTML pages, then do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what your'e asking, but assuming you're asking how you can *hide* elements that have *both* the classes `.SocialBar` and `.PersonalHome-interests`, but *show* elements that *only* have the class `.SocialBar`, all you need to do is **combine** the class selectors into one as `.SocialBar.PersonalHome-interests.u-mbg`, and hide that.

Because you're specifically targetting elements that have both classes, the element that only has one of the two classes will not have the `display: none` rule apply to it (and so it will remain visible).

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.SocialBar.PersonalHome-interests.u-mbg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="SocialBar">Visible</div>
<div class="SocialBar PersonalHome-interests u-mbg">Hidden</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for you help :)